# Filter rows according to a rule with 2 dataframes in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes:

```
t:
med score
a   3
b   1
v   2
c   2
f   1
```

and

```
p:
  med score
    a   1
    b   1
    v   2
    c   3
    f   3
```

I am using dplyr package to filter all the rows in t where score == 1:

```
t %>% filter(score == 1)
```

I am getting:

```
med score
b   1
f   1
```

I am trying to go to p df, filter the rows above (b,f) and update them to 3.
For some reason `p %>% filter(med == t[[1]])` doesn't work.

Please advise how can I achieve the above goal.

P.S
Here is what I am doing:

```
temp <- p %>% filter(score == 1)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
n <- filter(t, med == temp[[1]])
```

Then to update the scores of t according to the subdf n to be 3 for example.

Comment: Your dataframe `t` is not modified after filtering. You're still trying to use `t` as it is. Also, I don't think that `t[[1]]` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = read.table(text = "
               med score
               a   3
               b   1
               v   2
               c   2
               f   1
               ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

p = read.table(text = "
               med score
               a   1
               b   1
               v   2
               c   3
               f   3
               ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

# get the med values from p where score = 1
# save them as a vector
med_p = p$med[p$score == 1]

# update values in corresponding rows of t
t$score[t$med %in% med_p] = 3

# updated t
t

#   med score
# 1   a     3
# 2   b     3
# 3   v     2
# 4   c     2
# 5   f     1
```

You mentioned some functions in your comments, so in case this is a part of a bigger process you can use this process (my answer) as a function:

```
t = read.table(text = "
               med score
               a   3
               b   1
               v   2
               c   2
               f   1
               ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

p = read.table(text = "
               med score
               a   1
               b   1
               v   2
               c   3
               f   3
               ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

UpdateTable = function(dt_to_update, dt_control, input, update) {
    med_p = dt_control$med[dt_control$score == input]
    dt_to_update$score[dt_to_update$med %in% med_p] = update
    dt_to_update
    }

# old version
t

#   med score
# 1   a     3
# 2   b     1
# 3   v     2
# 4   c     2
# 5   f     1

# update version using the function
UpdateTable(t,p,1,3)

#   med score
# 1   a     3
# 2   b     3
# 3   v     2
# 4   c     2
# 5   f     1
```

Comment: How can I perform the task using my dataframes? It's part of a function that gets them as dataframe and asks if the value of med in p is 1 go to t same med and update the score.

Comment: I don't know how your functions looks like, but you can definitely use the above process as another function. Would that help?

Comment: I will share what I do, p is my control df:
temp <- p %>% filter(score == 1)
Now I want filter t to get temp's rows and update the score.

Comment: I'm confused because in your example above you first filter on `t` and not on `p`. Can you post above what your output should look like?

Comment: One of the df's is a control one say p. It doesn't really matter.
I am filtering on p, and going to t, filter med values to be equal to filtered p, assign new value to the score.

Comment: Ok, I think it's a bit more clear now. And the new value is 3? And will be the replacement for all rows you find, right?

Comment: Yep, exactly! Filter the first df, go to the second one, update the appropriate "rows"/med values with a different score.

Comment: So I don't need to use dplyr here?

Comment: No. You could, but don't really need it. Better to use a solution with no package dependencies when possible.

Comment: Antonio, many thanks for your time and such simple answer, it was my pleasure to learn from you! BRAVO!

Comment: Added a second part in the answer in case you want a function. Easier to apply it within a bigger process, or apply it in many cases.